# How to configure server to allow large file downloads?

Tags: apache, nginx, download, apache-config

I can download 1+ Gb files with no problem from my server. Today uploaded 2.3 GB file and discovered that I can't download it, downloading gets interrupted after 1GB and it happens for every user. I tried Firefox 15, latest Chrome, and IE9.

Server:
Apache 2.2.22
fcgi
eAccelerator
CPnginx

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do your log files say anything?

Answer (score 5):

I think I just faced the same problem, hopefully this might help others.

My server is set up to proxy requests to Apache through Nginx using the [`ngx_http_proxy_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html). The [`proxy_max_temp_file_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_max_temp_file_size) directive of this module defaults to `1024m` and is what was causing my problem.

Try adding the line `proxy_max_temp_file_size 5120m;` within a http, server or location directive in your `nginx.conf` file and reload nginx's config file with `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the default max download size apache sets is around 2 Gb and you can override it by tweaking [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) in your httpd.conf. Not sure why it would stop at 1 Gb though, that would make me think the problem is something else.. Hope this helps.