# PHP File Downloads all stop exactly at 1GB

Tags: php, file, download

I have a script setup so users can download files via a php script (one time use link) however when the file size reaches 1GB it fails to download any further.

It stops exactly at 1GB

Is there some setting in php.ini that would allow me to adjust it to go beyound 1GB?  I have tried changing most of the settings below but i dont see anything that would relate to a 1GB file size ...

Example: www.url.com/file.php?download=filename.zip (uses the below php code)

```
<?php
 $DownloadableFilesDirectory = "/dl/secret";
 $FileRenamePrependCharacters = "odroid_";

 if( ! empty($FileRenamePrependCharacters) ) { $FileRenamePrependCharacters = 
 ltrim($FileRenamePrependCharacters); }
 $DownloadableFilesDirectory = 
 preg_replace('/^\/*/','/',$DownloadableFilesDirectory);
 $DownloadableFilesDirectory = 
 preg_replace('/\/*$/','',$DownloadableFilesDirectory);
 $Directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$DownloadableFilesDirectory;
 if( empty($_GET['download']) ) { exit; }
 if( empty($_GET['savefile']) ) { $_GET['savefile'] = $_GET['download']; }
 $Dfile = $Directory.'/'.$_GET['download'];
 $size = filesize($Dfile);
 if( ! $size )
{
    echo '<p><b>The download file is empty or was not located.</b></p>';
    exit;
 }
 $ctype = 'application/octet-stream';
 header('Cache-control: private');
 header("Content-Type: $ctype");
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_GET['savefile'].'"');
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header("Content-Length: $size");
 @readfile($Dfile);
 if( empty($FileRenamePrependCharacters) ) { unlink($Dfile); }
 else
 {
    $pieces = explode('/',$Dfile);
    $pieces[count($pieces)-1] = $FileRenamePrependCharacters . 
 $pieces[count($pieces)-1];
    rename($Dfile,implode('/',$pieces));
  }
 exit;
 ?>
```

[image: Php Settings]

Comment: How exactly are you serving the file?

Comment: what is your server? Apache or nginx? There are settings to limit download in Apache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure server to allow large file downloads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232078/how-to-configure-server-to-allow-large-file-downloads)

Comment: www.url.com/file.php?download=filename.zip 
www.url.com/download.php?key=key5b6301db49f094.90762935&i=0

Comment: Maybe you reaches the max_execution_time limit, it depends on the way you send the file.

Comment: Let me rephrase: what is the PHP code you use to enable that download?

Comment: Apache i believe

Comment: Hopefully you're streaming the file and aren't loading the file entirely in memory.

Comment: Added the php code to the post

Comment: It might help to remove the `@` for starters…

Comment: the file does start to download, but fails at 1GB

Comment: @deceze it might help to never use `@` at all, in my opinion, even for experienced devs. Have you tried to expand the max_execution_time to see if it send more than 1GB ?

Comment: Yes i have, i set the max_execution_time to 500000000000000000 no change

Comment: maybe you should try the `set_time_limit(0)` directive in the begenning of your file. I'm not sure a large number like the one you set can be handled correctly accordingly to the architecture of your server...

Answer (score 0):

unless you're getting errors like `PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of ??? seconds exceeded in foo.php on line ?` in the error log, or being stupid and saving all the downloaded contents in ram and get errors like `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of ??? bytes exhausted (tried to allocate ??? bytes) in foo.php on line ?`  in the error log (and you're not doing that, going by the code you posted), this is not a PHP problem, it's a problem with the web server you're using. (nginx? apache? lighthttpd? microsoft's IIS? some proxy? some load balancer ala Cloudflare?), start your investigation there.

Comment: the readfile() function doesn't load the entire file in memory. And a lack of experience or knowledge is not a proof of stupidity :/

Comment: I just looked at php.ini settings  it says 
Server API LiteSpeed V7.1
PHP Version 7.0.3

Comment: @DouglasLittlefield then check the LiteSpeed configuration / error logs, the problem is almost certainly with LiteSpeed

Comment: @DouglasLittlefield and what configuration is it using?

Comment: would it do any harm if i post the link to view the php.ini settings?

Comment: @DouglasLittlefield in the vast majority of cases, no. for example, here is 1 of my servers: http://ratma.net/phpinfo.php - however, if you use the `mysql.default_user` / `mysql.default_password` / `mysqli.default_pw` php.ini configuration options, then it's a problem. check for these options before publishing the ini. (but actually using those settings is a terrible design choice anyway..)